# Add NSDictionary to NSManagedObject Category

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject

I would like to add a NSDictionary into a NSManagedObject Category class (or the NSManagedObject class itself) 
   When I do this, and I try to access the property, an exception is thrown.

Is this actually possible? I can't add this property as transient in the model because there is no NSDictionary Data Type, of course.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code. Are you trying to transfer data from a dictionary or set a transformable property?

Comment: Or maybe you're missing the existence of transformable on the data type setting...

Comment: Actually, the transformable attribute did the trick. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you have currently created the property or what the exception is, but from the description you give it sounds like you should be setting the attribute in the Core Data model to be `transformable`. Setting it to be `transformable` will cause the `NSDictionary` to be archived (and unarchived) as you use it using the standard `NSCoding` protocol. Be sure that everything you put into the dictionary supports the `NSCoding` protocol so that it is properly archived and restored.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! There was no need in this case to post the code. Your answer solved perfectly my issue. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Using `transformable` is the way. Below are few more insights on the transformable property.

> The Transformable data type is a special data type that allows us to
>   create attributes based on an Objective-C class (custom objects). This
>   data type is heavily used for storing instances of UIImage, UIColor,
>   and so on. As the information stored in the persistent store has to be
>   in the form of NSData instance, while using Transformable data type,
>   we need to create Value Transformers to convert the custom object
>   (information in attribute of Transformable data type) into an instance
>   of NSData (before storing in the persistent store) and to convert the
>   instance of NSData back to custom object while retrieving from the
>   persistent store.